# Django cms select instead list in admin filters

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.7 and need to make filter in admin page so

```
class CityFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _("Cities")
    parameter_name = "cities"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ((c.id, _(c.name)) for c in City.objects.all())
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not self.value():
            return queryset

        objs = User.objects.filter(
            city=self.value()
        ).values_list('user__id', flat=True)
        return queryset.filter(id__in=objs)
```

And I have + 200 cities and it looks not good in admin (as list) How can I change this list to something like select2?

Comment: https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2 ?

Comment: but how to implement this in admin filter?